# bootstrap collapse not collapsing after second click

Tags: twitter-bootstrap-3

i used twitter bootstrap collapse and the problem is that after the second click on the a tag (to open and hide the div) the div is not hidden.
i see that in the first time i click on a tag the 'in' class disappear and after that is staying (what makes the div appear).
i tried to copy the exact code from bootstrap site (without any changes) and it keeps going.
i read some post in stackoverflow that say the problem came from includes more than 1 bootstrap js or css (i check and it's notmy case).
there is something that blocking the collapse.

Comment: your question in not clean and also please add some code that you have so that we can better help you.

Comment: Could you please post your html code, so that we can take a look

Comment: for now i use the code from bootstrap http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#collapse and still the same problem

Answer (score 0):

http://twitteer_D.com/javascript/#collapse/Twitteer_D used twitter bootstrap collapse and the problem is that after the second click on the a tag (to open and hide the div) the div is not hidden. i see that in the first time i click on a tag the 'in' class disappear and after that is staying (what makes the div appear). i tried to copy the exact code from bootstrap site (without any changes) and it keeps going. i read some post in stackoverflow that say the problem came from includes more than 1 bootstrap js or css (i check and it's notmy case). there is something that blocking the collapse.

Comment: Metahttps://www.website.com/verify-email/?key=E8D52A83-7A72-4566-B3AF-9A95EC95E15B